# Running Chrome in kiosk mode not working?

Tags: google-chrome, active-directory

I am trying to run Chrome in "kiosk" mode but for some reason it is not working. I tried all the possible switch combinations and disable running Chrome in backround through GPO but it is not working.

Here is the current link I am running.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -ignore-certificate-errors --chrome --kisok --fullscreen https://web.page.com
```

Is there any other setting that I need to check or configure?

Here is also a list of tasks that are running:

```
**System Idle Process
armsvc.exe
audiodg.exe
cb.exe
CcmExec.exe
cmd.exe
concentr.exe
conhost.exe
csrss.exe
dwm.exe
DWRCS.EXE
DWRCST.EXE
EngineServer.exe
explorer.exe
FrameworkService.exe
igfxCUIService.exe
igfxEM.exe
igfxHK.exe
lsass.exe
lsm.exe
McShield.exe
McTray.exe
mfeann.exe
mfevtps.exe
naPrdMgr.exe
PresentationFontCache.exe
RAVBg64.exe
RAVCpl64.exe
Receiver.exe
redirector.exe
SearchIndexer.exe
SelfServicePlugin.exe
services.exe
shstat.exe
smss.exe
spoolsv.exe
ssonsvr.exe
svchost.exe
System
taskeng.exe
taskhost.exe
TCPSVCS.EXE
UdaterUI.exe
VsTskMgr.exe
wfcrun32.exe
wininit.exe
winlogon.exe
WmiPrvSE.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Deni said he was running RSOP and it turned out that the GPO setting for blocking Chrome to run with kiosk mode was not applying. He said he fixed it (I am assuming he used `gpupdate /force` in Command Prompt to update GPO). He said the parameters that he is using is

`--ignore-certificate-errors` and `--kiosk`

Comment: I am already creating a shortcut through PowerShell because I need to deploy it to multiple desktops so adding a new user is not a solution. Also, there is no Chrome instances running in the background.

Comment: Double check if there are any running. I am almost positive they are. Look at every tab of task manager.

Comment: I added a list of running tasks and services to main question, I do not see Chrome anywhere, is there any other task that would cause that issue?

Comment: Did you check under users, details, and processes? If so I will look into it further.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? What doesnt work?

Comment: Try putting another "-" before -ignore-cer........ because according to the post you only have one

Comment: @ Brendan: That is not it, I removed that part. It is opening Chrome in normal mode not Kiosk mode.

Comment: You have a typo in your original question.  It's *kiosk* not *kisok*.

Comment: @DeniBeslic Is the above comment your issue?

Comment: It was not a typo. I have run RSOP and it turned out that GPO for blocking Chrome to run it back was not applying. I have fixed that issue and now it is working fine. The parameters that I am using are "--ignore-certificate-errors --kiosk"

Comment: @DeniBeslic If it worked please accept my answer so in the future anyone with the same issue can fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @DeniBeslic did it work? If so please mark my answer as correct so people in the future can fix this issue!